# list in list in a single linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have this csv

| Id | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | 20 |
| 1 | Maria | 16 |

i want to make a CSV Reader that splits csv's in the elements `header` and `data`.
`Header` is just a string array that saves the headers and works well.

i have issues when it comes to saving the `data`. I want to save the csv in a list of lists without the headers and this is how i am doing it:

```cs
                var predata = file
                    .Skip(1)
                    .ToList();

                List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();

                for (int i = 0; i < predata.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<string> templist = predata[i]
                        .Split(';')
                        .ToList();

                    data.Add(templist);
                }
```

this looks very inefficient and i would like to know if there is any way to do all this, but much shorter. Maybe even in one single linq query.

pls dont report this question, im giving my best to explain my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big thing we can do to improve performance and shorten the code is avoid calling `.ToList()` more often than needed. In fact, if you can accept `IEnumerable<string[]>` instead of `List<List<string>>` we can get it down to this, which should also run faster and allocate **MUCH** less memory:

```
var data = file.Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(';'));
```

If you really *must* have `List<List<string>>` we can adjust it to the following:

```
var data = file.Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(';').ToList()).ToList();
```

But again: every call to `.ToList()` adds more RAM and CPU use to your program. Best to wait to do that for as long as possible.

---

I'm also curious about where the `file` variable came from. It seems likely it's the result of either `File.ReadAllLines()` or `File.ReadLines()`, and I can tell you the latter will again be **MUCH** more efficient for this than the former.

So you want something like this:

```
var header = File.ReadLines("...").Take(1);
var data = File.ReadLines("...").Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(';'));
```

Note at this point `data` *has not yet read through the file*. However, you can use it in a `foreach` loop or with a linq extension, and it will read through file in a just-in-time way, such that only one line from the file is ever needed in memory at a time.

This is more efficient, *even when you will eventually show the entire file contents on the screen* or otherwise fully load the file, because it allows you to save RAM (and CPU) while translating the raw data from the file into the final structure you want for display or other purposes.

---

Separate from all of this, something you can do to *really* improve performance is get a dedicated csv parser from NuGet, especially as `.Split()` is known to be a little slower as well as fail in numerous edge cases.

Comment: I do indeed use `ReadAllLines`. Why is `ReadLines` faster? I use `ReadAllLines` to be able to use the index feature to get the headers of a csv file.

Comment: `ReadAllLines()` needs enough memory to hold the entire file. `ReadLines()` only needs enough memory to hold the longest line in the file, plus a little extra. If you want the first line, instead of using an index try `Take(1)` in the same way you used `Skip(1)` (and then reopen the file to read the data lines, because the `Take()` method will complete the enumeration.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure - just use `.Select`:

```
var data = predata.Select(p = > p.Split(';'));
```

This will actually give you an `IEnumerable<string[]>` which you can iterate over. If you *need* lists, just add `ToList` at each level:

```
var data = predata.Select(p = > p.Split(';').ToList()).ToList();
```

And you can skip `predata` by just changing it to `file.Skip(1)` (there's no need to call `ToList` after the `Skip` if all you're doing is iterating).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
var data=file.select(x=>x.Split(';').ToList()).ToList();
```